# How to change region of existing Firebase project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a project that is located in the Central America region, but since I can choose a European region, I would like to change the location of the firestore and storage. Is it possible to do this without deleting the existing project?

**Updated**

Response from technical support:

> Thank you for reaching out to us. Currently, once you select a location for your project, you cannot change it.
>
> You might find this documentation useful for additional information.
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#top_of_page
>
> I hope this information has been helpful for you.

**Updated 2**
Answer at Google Groups

> Unfortunately we don't support changing regions once resources are created. You'll have to create a new project and migrate data, etc.

and the do not plan implement it in near future

Answer (score 28):

When you create a Firestore database in a project, both the mode (Native mode | Datastore mode) and the location are immutable choices. We're working infrastructure to enable us to improve this in the future, but for the time being this is not changeable.

The way to get the same result is to create an additional database to the project, and then use managed import and export ([Datastore mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) | [Native mode](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import)) to move data between the databases.

For Firebase storage, you can always [create new buckets](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/multiplying-power-firebase-storage.html) in different locations.

Comment: Out of interest, does Firestore optimize the read requests globally? Say I have 1 million users in Thailand all of a sudden, are read replications placed there automatically?

Comment: Hi Dan, super interested in that topic as we want/need to move our app, including a highly engaged user base and all related data to a new region, meaning firestore and storage (the latter seems slightly more straight forward). How far have you come with that infrastructure and what process would you recommend for a smooth transition? Highly appreciating your answer.

Comment: I'm joining @AlexeiS. it is extremely important for us as well 

Comment: Same here. At a bare minimum there should be a huge warning when you create a new project that reads *"You're about to create a project in a region that is not the closest to you. Are you sure? If not go change it at XYZ"*.

Comment: Is it still not possible to change the region?

Comment: Also very interested in this topic. We also have a need to move our app including a lot of users.  Hoping that it will be a possibility soon

Answer (score 0):

I changed the region successfully by deleting the database in the Google Cloud Console and creating a new one named (default) in the desired region