# How to make firebase storage reference to a certain bucket?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

[image]

I create a new bucket in a region near from my users location (asia-southeast1) so hopefully it will fetch the image faster in the client side, I want to upload image and also to download image from that new bucket.

but I don't how to make reference to that new bucket. usually I use the code below in Android to create reference for default bucket

```
val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("profilePicture")
```

so how to download and upload image from that bucket? I assume that I have to make some change when creating the reference, but I don't know how to pointing the reference to that new bucket

Answer (score 1):

After getting info from [@samthecodingman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291630#comment106650031_60291630) and testing it, I can set a reference to use a certain bucket using the code below

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://yourBucketNameHere").reference.child("profilePicture")
```

Don't forget to add **gs://** in your string as [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage#getInstance(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

In the API documentation for [FirebaseStorage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage), it says:

> FirebaseStorage is a service that supports uploading and downloading
>   large objects to Google Cloud Storage. **Pass a custom instance of
>   FirebaseApp to getInstance(FirebaseApp) which will initialize it with
>   a storage location (bucket) specified via setStorageBucket(String).**
>
> Otherwise, if you call getReference() without a FirebaseApp, the
>   FirebaseStorage instance will initialize with the default FirebaseApp
>   obtainable from getInstance(). The storage location in this case will
>   come the JSON configuration file downloaded from the web.

The bolded text is what you will need to do.  Initialize a new [FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html) instance using a [FirebaseOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.html) object using a builder where you called [setStorageBucket()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.Builder.html#setStorageBucket(java.lang.String)) with the name of the bucket you want to use.

Then, when you call [FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)), passing that FirebaseApp instance, your references will come from that bucket.