# how to properly initialize firebase app that can be used more than once?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

usually I initialize firebase in my activity just like this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // usually initializing firebase just like this
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

}
```

but now I need that `firebaseApp` to be passed to get `FirebaseStorage` instance like this:

```
    // set firebase option
    val optionBuilder = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    optionBuilder.setStorageBucket("newBucket")
    val firebaseOption = optionBuilder.build()

    // initialize firebase app
    val app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this,firebaseOption)

    // create reference, pass app to firebase storage
    val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app).reference.child("profilePicture")
```

but the problem is.....

I need to create that firebase storage reference in more than one place. so how how to properly initialize firebase app so that I can use it in more than one place ?

do I need to initialize it in MainActivity **AND** recreate it again whenever I need to make storage reference ? it seems like a bad idea, but I don't know .... please help :)

Comment: Any reason not to use `FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://newBucket");`?

Comment: @samthecodingman hmm I am not sure, this is actually a continuation from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274587/how-to-make-firebase-storage-reference-to-a-certain-bucket could you please help me sir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize it once and store it in a place where they can all access it - a singleton.